# Is it a bad practice to iterate over a Flask SQLAlchemy object using __dict__?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

To build a dynamic user update route on Flask, I have iterate over the user Flask SQLAlchemy object using the dunder `__dict__`:

```
parameters = ['name'] # Valid parameters after the Regex filter was applied

for parameter in parameters:
    user.__dict__[parameter] = request.form.get(parameter)
```

I have done this to avoid the usage of `ifs`. To ensure that only valid parameters are present in `parameters`, I have applied a Regex pattern that filters the valid parameters received in the `request` for the user route, and I have documented this aspect on the doc string.

I'm asking if iterate over a Flask SQLAlchemy object using `__dict__` is it a bad practice because if I print the `user.__dict__`, I receive all parameters, even those that aren't on the Regex filter, i.g, password, date created, etc; and should never be updated by this route.

I have found another [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446027/sqlalchemy-iterating-through-data) that uses get all columns in SQLAlchemy, but I think that at the end its similar to the approach that I'm using...

Obs: the implemented route can update specific attributes from user or all of them, using the same route

Comment: Yes it is; it does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013965/sqlalchemy-commit-changes-to-object-modified-through-dict

Comment: In general: direct access from outside the class to a special method or var enclosed by double underscores is never best practice.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. I'm going try to use `setattr` indicate by @lIja.

Comment: Related as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272789/when-should-method-be-called-directly, in general it's better to use operators and available functions instead of magic methods and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into [marshmallow-sqlalchemy](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#de-serialize-your-data) to manage this sort of thing. I've found that there are very few use-cases where there is a problem, and `__dict__` is the best solution.

Here's an example application using it: [How do I produce nested JSON from database query with joins? Using Python / SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55534149/how-do-i-produce-nested-json-from-database-query-with-joins-using-python-sqla/55549437#55549437)